# Filter an array column based on a provided list

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following types in a dataframe:

```
 root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- items: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

input:

```
val rawData = Seq(("id1",Array("item1","item2","item3","item4")),("id2",Array("item1","item2","item3")))
val data = spark.createDataFrame(rawData)
```

and a list of items:

```
 val filter_list = List("item1", "item2")
```

I would like to filter out items that are non in the `filter_list`, similar to how `array_contains` would function, but its not working on a provided list of strings, only a single value.

so the output would look like this:

```
val rawData = Seq(("id1",Array("item1","item2")),("id2",Array("item1","item2")))
val data = spark.createDataFrame(rawData)
```

I tried solving this with the following UDF, but I probably mix types between Scala and Spark:

```
def filterItems(flist: List[String]) = udf {
  (recs: List[String]) => recs.filter(item => flist.contains(item))
}
```

I'm using Spark 2.2

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code is almost right. All you have to do is replace `List` with `Seq`

```
def filterItems(flist: List[String]) = udf {
  (recs: Seq[String]) => recs.filter(item => flist.contains(item))
}
```

It would also make sense to change signature from `List[String] => UserDefinedFunction` to  `SeqString] => UserDefinedFunction`, but it is not required.

Reference [SQL Programming Guide - Data Types](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types).

Comment: worked flawlessly, adding the curing call for full context:
`data.withColumn("filtercol", filterItems(filter_list)(col("_2")))`

Comment: Hi, I am trying to do the same thing with my data, I cannot understand what (col("_2") is referring to, can you please help me understand what col("_2") is? I could not see it in your question and I am very new to UDF in scala. thanks