# Dataframe explode lateral view and compare with arrray

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a spark Dataframe with the column called X. X is a string column containing a list of values separated by ','. Also, I have an array of values lets call it Y. What I am trying to do is filter my Dataframe where values in X after splitting by ',' are in Y. My final data frame should contain rows where none of the values in X match Y.

Following is the code I am trying to execute but it is super slow for my data set.

```
 val arrayMatches = udf { (a: mutable.WrappedArray[String],
                          b: mutable.WrappedArray[String]) =>
  a.intersect(b).nonEmpty
}

def asLitArray[T](xs: Seq[T]) = array(xs map lit: _*)

val col1 = col("X") // Column containing string values separated by "," ex: "abc,def,ghi,jkl"

// Y is array of string values like "abc, def, ghi". Size of Y is around 200k
val condition = !col1.isNull || !arrayMatches(split(col1, ","), asLitArray(Y))

val resultDF = myDataDF.filter(condition)
resultDF.count() // --> This step take ages.
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: In your condition, don't you mean `&&`?

Comment: Similar question has been asked here, this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249262/filter-an-array-column-based-on-a-provided-list

Comment: @oli No I need Or condition here.

Comment: Can you explain the logic you expect? I am not sure I understand. For instance, what do you expect for null values of `col1`?

Comment: can you post a sample of myDataDF.show()