# Filtering dataframe array items based on an external array with intersection

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to define a way to filter elements from WrappedArrays in DFs. The filter is based on an external list of elements.

Looking for a solutions I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249262/filter-an-array-column-based-on-a-provided-list?answertab=active#tab-top). It is very similar, but it seems not to work for me. I'm using Spark 2.4.0. This is my code:

```scala
val df = sc.parallelize(Array((1, Seq("s", "v", "r")),(2, Seq("r", "a", "v")),(3, Seq("s", "r", "t")))).toDF("foo","bar")


def filterItems(flist: Seq[String]) = udf {
  (recs: Seq[String]) => recs match {
    case null => Seq.empty[String]
    case recs => recs.intersect(flist)
  }}

df.withColumn("filtercol", filterItems(Seq("s", "v"))(col("bar"))).show(5)
```

My expected result would be:

```sh
+---+---------+---------+ 
|foo| bar|filtercol| 
+---+---------+---------+ 
| 1 |[s, v, r]|   [s, v]| 
| 2 |[r, a, v]|      [v]| 
| 3| [s, r, t]|      [s]| 
+---+---------+---------+
```

But I'm getting this error:

```sh
java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the build-in function in Spark 2.4 without too much effort actually:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{array_intersect, array, lit}

val df = sc.parallelize(Array((1, Seq("s", "v", "r")),(2, Seq("r", "a", "v")),(3, Seq("s", "r", "t")))).toDF("foo","bar")

val ar = Seq("s", "v").map(lit(_))
df.withColumn("filtercol", array_intersect($"bar", array(ar:_*))).show
```

Output:

```
+---+---------+---------+
|foo|      bar|filtercol|
+---+---------+---------+
|  1|[s, v, r]|   [s, v]|
|  2|[r, a, v]|      [v]|
|  3|[s, r, t]|      [s]|
+---+---------+---------+
```

The only tricky part is `Seq("s", "v").map(lit(_))` which will map each string into `lit(i)`. The `intersection` function accepts two arrays. The first one is the value of `bar` column. The second one is created it on the fly with `array(ar:_*)`, which will contain values of `lit(i)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass an attribute of ArrayType into an UDF, it arrives as an instance of `WrappedArray`, which is **not** a `List`. So you should change `recs` type to `Seq`, `IndexedSeq` or `WrappedArray`, normally I just use plain `Seq`:

```
def filterItems(flist: List[String]) = udf {
  (recs: Seq[String]) => recs match {
    case null => Seq.empty[String]
    case recs => recs.intersect(flist)
  }}
```

Comment: You are right about this. But it doesn't solve my problem. I could change of all List types to Seq types and error would still be the same. I have edited the question so this is not the issue. Thanks for your help.